# UPDATE all rows after 2nd row,by ADDING 1 to these rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  subject        position         visible

1   Home               1               1
2   About us           2               1
3   Our partners       3               1
18  Products           4               1
19  Extra              5               0
```

I want to add number 1 to all rows after position=2, like this:

```
id  subject        position         visible

1   Home               1               1
2   About us           2               1
3   Our partners       4               1
18  Products           5               1
19  Extra              6               0
```

I tried like this, but this doesnt work:

```
$row=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$count=mysql_num_rows($row);
$position=3;
$add=($position+1);
while($position<=$count)
{
    $sql="UPDATE subjects SET position=$add WHERE position=$position";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $add++;
    $position++;
}
```

After applying above code, my table looks like this:

```
id  subject        position         visible

1   Home               1               1
2   About us           2               1
3   Our partners       6               1
18  Products           6               1
19  Extra              6               0
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Please tell me you aren't doing updates inside your loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just:

```
UPDATE subjects SET position=position+1 WHERE position>2
```

Comment: Thank you.i tried now.but it makes position (1,2,7,8,9) instead of (1,2,4,5,6)

Comment: That's because you should run it ONCE, not in a loop. Just get rid of everything except a single `mysql_query` with that in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE subjects SET position=position + 1 WHERE position >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks.i tried.but it makes position (1,2,7,8,9) instead of (1,2,4,5,6).i cant understand why!

Answer (score 1):

```
 update subjects set position = position +1 where position >2
```